# Camel file consumer template - threads remaining alive

Tags: multithreading, file, apache-camel, out-of-memory, consumer

I have a problem very similar to http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/FTP-ConsumerTemplate-Threads-remaining-alive-td5548338.html.

How do you kill Camel locked threads on different endpoints? I tried to remove endpoints and stop ConsumerTemplate after setting doneUoW, but those didn't work.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried to upgrade to a newer release.

Comment: Have you tried version 2.10.x?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution of this?

Comment: How about `controlbus` to stop the routes consuming from the endpoint(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `&disconnect=true` on your FTP URI. With that, it will release the connection and by the same time, which may generate your locked threads.