# Camel File Consumer not stopping

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, apache-camel

I have a question similar to [camel-file-consumer-template-threads-remaining-alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207962/camel-file-consumer-template-threads-remaining-alive). I have a webapp running in a Tomcat container. I am using Camel version 2.10.4. In it I have I use the `File` component as a polling consumer. It is set up as follows:

```
from("/myDir"+
     "?delete=true"+
     "&startingDirectoryMustExist=true"+
     "&scheduledExecutorService=#mySpringManagedExecutorService")
```

This runs fine as expected but when I attempt to stop Tomcat I get the following message:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread
     named [MyExecuteService-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to
     create a memory leak.
```

After invoking the shutdown.sh script I invoke `ps -ef | grep tomcat` and the process is still running. If my app is not loaded or if I do not load this route in my app tomcat stops properly.

Comment: Same questions also posted on Apache Camel mailing list!

Comment: Correct. Wasn't sure at which location I would get a faster response. I will post the solution to both places.

Comment: A potential solution has been posted on nabble. Investigating...

Answer (score 0):

FYI, so the solution was posted on Nabble. This was that I needed to shutdown the executor service in Spring. I did this by adding a `destory-method="shutdown"` to the executor service.

FYI, I had set up the executor service this was so that I could have different thread names per route in a single context. Neither Spring nor Camel seems to provide this mechanism.

The Nabble thread is [here](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/File-consumer-thread-not-stopping-when-Tomcat-stopped-td5741668.html#a5741683)